# How to control insert operation in loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Is there any way to control or monitor loopback `insert operation` for specific model and after insert call a function?  for example: 
after submitting a form `if` form successfully inserted a verification mail sends to entered mail address or SMS to entered phone number

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});

var properties = {};
var options = {trackChanges: true };

var MyModel = loopback.Model.extend('Registration', properties, options);
MyModel.on('changeed', function(inst) {
  console.log('model with phonenumber %s has been changed', inst.phonenumber);
});
```

Comment: you could use mixins and add them to every model you want to observe

Comment: hi @victor-godoy, tnx .I will be appriciated  if you could guide me more.

Comment: with mixins you can extends additional logic to any Model but for your case I suggest to use Operation hooks https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to for a specific Model you should use [Operation hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html)

You have the 'before save' and 'after save' there you can run any additional logic you want like send the email.

./server/my-mode.js

```
MyModel.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    // When Create (POST)
    // ctx.instance have the json properties
    console.log("Triggers when create");
  } else {
    // When Update (UPDATE)
    // ctx.data have the json properties
    console.log("Triggers when update");
  }
  next();
});
```

./server/my-mode.js

```
MyModel.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.instance) {
    // When Create (POST)
    // ctx.instance have the json properties
    console.log("Triggers after create");

  } else {
    // When Update (UPDATE)
    // ctx.data have the json properties
    console.log("Triggers after update");
  }
  next();
});
```